# WCF config for a service class implementing multiple contracts on separate endpoints

Tags: wcf

I have a `MyService` class implementing `IService1` and `IService2` interfaces. I would like to expose these two contracts on two separate endpoints, like:

- `IService1` exposed on `/Service/S1`
- `IService2` exposed on `/Service/S2`

How would such a config look like?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this....

```
<services>      
  <service name="Service">
    <endpoint address="http://localhost:8080/Service/S1"
              binding="basicHttpBinding"
              contract="IService1"

     />

    <endpoint address="http://localhost:8080/Service/S2"
              binding="basicHttpBinding"
              contract="IService2 "

     />
  </service>
</services>
```

Comment: That doesn't seem to be what I'm looking for. MyService class is a class that implements both of the interfaces: IService1 and IService2. According to http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms731303.aspx service.name attribute has to map to a type name. If MyService is the only type implementing the contracts, it can't be used twice in the config.

Comment: @Marcin Seredynski: you're right - the service **class** cannot be used twice in the config - only one <service name="service"> possible. **BUT:** you can still define **TWO SEPARATE ENDPOINTS** on two separate addresses, one for each of the **CONTRACTS** that the service class implements - that's what you're looking for, no??

Answer (score 1):

You can just use a service with two endpoints, like this:

```
<services>      
  <service name="MyNamespace.MyService">
    <endpoint address="/Service/S1"
              binding="basicHttpBinding"
              contract="IService1" />
    <endpoint address="/Service/S2"
              binding="basicHttpBinding"
              contract="IService2 " />
    <host>
      <baseAddresses>
        <add baseAddress="http://localhost:8080/"/>
      </baseAddresses>
    </host>
  </service>
</services>
```

EDIT: Added base address

Comment: For some reason this approach doesn't want to work: Service cannot be started. System.InvalidOperationException: Could not find a base address that matches scheme http for the endpoint with binding BasicHttpBinding. Registered base address schemes are [].

Comment: Just a note, I'm instantiating ServiceHost by passing it an instance of the service and an endpoint Uri.