# Create proxy from a service with two contracts and endpoints

Tags: wcf

I am having trouble adding a service to my app.config that implements two contracts, and thus needs two endpoints.

See this question for a basic example of what I am trying to do:

[WCF config for a service class implementing multiple contracts on separate endpoints](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3936239/wcf-config-for-a-service-class-implementing-multiple-contracts-on-separate-endpo)

I really want to use the Service Reference in my clients to create and maintain the proxies for me, but when I try to do this with a service with two endpoints, I get the following error in the details when it tries to download the metadata:

> Metadata contains a reference that cannot be resolved

Here is an example of how I have the service setup in my app.config in my wcf service library:

```
  <service name="MyService">
    <endpoint address="Address1" binding="wsDualHttpBinding" bindingConfiguration=""
      name="Service1" contract="IService1" />
    <endpoint address="Address2" binding="wsDualHttpBinding" bindingConfiguration=""
      name="Service2" contract="IService2" />
    <endpoint address="mex" binding="mexHttpBinding" bindingConfiguration=""
      name="mex" contract="IMetadataExchange" />
    <host>
      <baseAddresses>
        <add baseAddress="http://localhost:8732/Design_Time_Addresses/MyService/" />
      </baseAddresses>
    </host>
  </service>
```

I feel like I am missing something simple.  When I remove one of the end points, everything works fine.  But if I have both end points in there, it can't resolve the metadata.

I have tried removing the base address and using full addresses, and with different ports but all paths I have tried lead to the same error.

---

Edit:
I should clarify why I am trying to do this in the first place I guess. I have a singleton service that I would like clients to be able to connect to. But there are some methods that I do not want clients to have access to. I thought separating the admin methods and the client methods into two separate contracts would be a good start.

To be even more clear, this is a game server.  I want to be able to start new instances of the game server and send it a map and things like that.
I don't want gamers to have access to methods like LoadMap() or anything like that.
I really want to separate the methods and callbacks that the game client would have versus the methods and callbacks a match making service or server admin would have.

I also would like them to be separate contracts just to make it easier to read and maintain.

However, if there is a better way to do that, I am open for suggestions.

Comment: Does IService2 exist? Which one do you remove to make it work?

Comment: Yeah, both exist, I can remove either endpoint from the app.config of the WCF service library and the service reference in the client finds the one I did not remove.  I tried it again with by creating a default WCF service library.  I then added an interface with the ServiceContract attribute and implemented that interface in my service and setup my WCF config similar to what I posted.  I used the default wsHttpBinding and got the same result when my test client tried to resolve the Service Reference.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Took me a while to figure this out.  I tore down my project and started rebuilding it from the beginning until it broke.

Apparently you cannot have two callback methods with the same name in your callback contracts if you try to do this.

Example:

```
public interface IService1Callback
{
    [OperationContract(IsOneWay = true)]
    void GetDataDone();
}

public interface IService2Callback
{
    [OperationContract(IsOneWay = true)]
    void GetDataDone();
}
```

If you then set these as the callback contracts on your service contracts like this:

```
[ServiceContract
(Namespace = "ServiceLib", 
SessionMode = SessionMode.Required, CallbackContract = typeof(IService1Callback))]
public interface IService1
{
    [OperationContract(IsInitiating = true)]
    string GetData(int value);
}

[ServiceContract
(Namespace = "ServiceLib", 
SessionMode = SessionMode.Required, CallbackContract = typeof(IService2Callback))]
public interface IService2
{
    [OperationContract(IsInitiating = true)]
    string GetOtherData(int value);
}
```

you will end up getting the error I mentioned in my original question.

I believe this is because the end points cannot figure out which callback contract the method comes from since they have the same name, so the metadata cannot resolve the reference.

Luckily I won't have callbacks with the same name, but I was stuck on this for a while because I had just setup some dummy methods to get things going.